# The Principal in an MVC4 app with VS 2012 is a RolePrincipal instead of ClaimsPrincipal after running the "Identity and Access" wizard

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, wif

The MVC 4 app created by the default (internet) template in Visual Studio 2012 returns a RolePrincipal after running the "identity and access..." wizard.

The wizard creates a trust relationship with an STS (either a real or a "development" time STS).

If inspected, the User object will be of type ***RolePrincipal***. A consequence of this, is that User.IsInRole resolves against the local roles database instead of the claims set.

[image]

I was expecting a ***ClaimsPrincipal***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the new Oauth support. It is using the new simplemembership which underneath ends up using all the providers.

Removing the `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` attribute on the account controller is not enough because the initialization happens in the ***WebMatrix.WebData*** assembly:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof (PreApplicationStartCode), "Start")]
```

***PreApplicationStartCode.Start*** ends up calling:

```
WebSecurity.PreAppStartInit();
```

That, if inspected, shows:

```
     ...
SimpleRoleProvider simpleRoleProvider = WebSecurity.CreateDefaultSimpleRoleProvider("AspNetSqlRoleProvider", currentDefault2);
      Roles.Providers.Remove("AspNetSqlRoleProvider");
      Roles.Providers.Add((ProviderBase) simpleRoleProvider);
...
```

The way to disable all this "magic" is with this setting in the web.config:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

Comment: This answer led me to the fix, which for me was to remove the WebMatrix.WebData reference from my project.